error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8) - 1
When I was cloning a GitHub repository on a HPC, at first it was running:
remote: Enumerating objects: 1059, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1059/1059), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (951/951), done.
Receiving objects:  23% (434/1809), 1.21 GiB | 9.59 MiB/s
It suddenly stopped and said: error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
error: 7130 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
how to solve this issue?
I have already tried:
git config --global http.postBuffer 10000M or
git clone --depth 1 repository's http
but they did not work. A little help please if you know how to solve this issue. Thank you in advance!

That looks like a timeout. How long did it run before stopping?

Try Powershell for cloning GitHub repository..

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

try to be more particular to the question being asked. your answer is no where close or at least does not explain why the OP should consider it
